# Livewire and flatpickr: null data on change

Tags: php, laravel-livewire, flatpickr

**Disclaimer:** I know there are already a few questions regarding coupling Livewire and flatpickr, yet I don't understand the solutions provided, since they are very different from how I'm approaching the problem. That said, I'm still learning Livewire, so I might just be doing it wrong.

I have a Livewire component where I use flatpickr to select both date and time.

```
<div class="mb-3" >
    <input id="chosendatetime" type="datetime-local" name="chosendatetime" value="{{ old('chosendatetime') }}" 
               wire:model.debounce.500ms="chosendatetime" />
</div>
```

In the blade component, I have also the script section to init flatpickr:

```
<script>
    flatpickr("#chosendatetime", {
        enableTime: true,
        dateFormat: "d-m-Y H:i",
    });
</script>
```

The date picker is rendered correctly, but when I change its value the data sent by the client is empty.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add `wire:ignore` to the div element, like this:

```
<div class="mb-3" wire:ignore>
    <input id="chosendatetime" type="datetime-local" name="chosendatetime" value="{{ old('chosendatetime') }}" 
               wire:model.debounce.500ms="chosendatetime" />
</div>
```

This directive lets Livewire know that it should skip this part of the page and not change it when the component refreshes. If you don't use it, Livewire could replace the flatpickr instance and make it stop working.

Comment: Although I remember trying it once, before posting the question, this time worked as expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine, IF you have setup your Livewire properly.

- Make sure you have a public property called **chosendatetime** in your Livewire class `public $chosendatetime;`
- Add a function called **updatedChosenDatetime()** and `dd()` the **$this->chosendatetime** to see if the value is received or not
- Make sure you have included `@livewireStyles` and `@livewireScripts` inside your layout blade.
- Make sure you have included FlatPickr JS and CSS

The Livewire class will look like

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class FlatPickr extends Component
{
    public $chosendatetime;

    public function updatedChosenDatetime()
    {
        dd($this->chosendatetime);
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.flat-pickr');
    }
}
```

Comment: My code was setup as you suggested, but I still received an empty string from Livewire's callback. Adding `wire:ignore` did the trick.